# My spec page on my HP Pavilion HPE-112y desktop indicates 8GB installed Ram

Tags: memory

I thought it had been upgraded to 16 GB. If so, shouldn't that show on the Device spec page shown below?

Device name mike-desktop
Processor   AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 925 Processor   2.80 GHz
**Installed RAM 8.00 GB**
Device ID   DBAC5235-3D97-439B-9772-A2725AF1BA2C
Product ID  00326-10000-00000-AA722
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Is there another way to find out without removing the cover and looking inside the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the BIOS settings when the machine boots (by pressing F10/F2) and see how many (and what size) DIMMs the BIOS thinks are installed.

If the BIOS agrees with the OS and states that only 8GB is installed, but you're confident that 16GB should be fitted, it may be worth opening the case and checking that a DIMM hasn't been unseated in transit.

Obviously, if opening the case will void the warranty you may wish to follow John's advice and contact the vendor you bought the machine from.

Comment: A better way would be to use software that provides the exact make and model of the memory  then look that up online.  Not sure how to do this in Windows but dmidecide will do it in Linux.